# Focus next input when pressing Tab in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have multiple editable inputs on my screen .

Between theses editable inputs I have buttons and disabled inputs.

The actual behavior is when I press Tab the html elements between the current input and next one get focused. I should so press Tab until I get to my sibling Input.

This behavior is not what I want.

What I'm expecting is that when I press Tab the next desired Input get Focused.

Here a simplified code

```html
    <ng-container #form *ngFor="let elm of elms; let currIndex = index" cdkTrapFocus
        [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true">
      <app-item [index]="currIndex">
    Here I get a line with : span, disabled input , editable input then a button
      </app-item>
    </ng-container>
```

I tried to use a directive that focus next sibling depending on it's not working due to complex nested html elements inside `app-item`.

I would like to know if there is a much simpler solution using [Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview) and "tag" desired items to focus using `tab` key ?

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically add `tabindex="-1"` attribute to input element, and when you click `tab` key, that element will be skipped.

So on each button and disabled inputs, just add `tabindex="-1"` attribute.

```
<input tabindex="-1" />
```